# Trying to make App Store loading bar

Tags: ios, jailbreak, deb

When an app is downloaded from the app store, it goes directly to the home screen with a nice looking loading bar (to show when the app is downloading/installing). JailbreakMe 3.0 utilizes this. Does anyone know how to use this? I'm trying to make an install script to install a set of .deb files on an iPhone, and I'd like the App Store install style. Thanks in advance.

(Got a picture of it if nobody understand's what I'm talking about)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the JailbreakMe 3.0 source code : https://github.com/comex/star_/tree/master/install